# how to set image inside framelayout

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, overlapping, android-framelayout

I want to set image inside the `FrameLayout` but is overlapping the framelayout's background

[image: right now how its looking]

Comment: Change order of Images in Framelayout. You placing Image as last in FrameLayout. First you place an Image and place other items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is sample example, https://snag.gy/IrawbT.jpg

> item last put on the stack will be drawn on top of the items below it.
>   This layout makes it very easy to draw on top of other layouts,
>   especially for tasks such as button placement.
>
> To arrange the children inside of a `FrameLayout` use the
>   `android:layout_gravity` attribute along with whatever `android:padding`
>   and `android:margin` you need.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <!-- Child1 is drawn first -->
    <!-- Child2 is drawn over Child1 -->
    <!-- Child3 is drawn over Child1 and Child2 -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/child1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:text="Child 3"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/child2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="40dip"
        android:src="@color/childs"
        android:text="Child 2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/child3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="Image"
        android:src="@color/_dark_gray" />
</FrameLayout >
```

Comment: The xml is incorrect. in that sequence, child 3 goes first in the stack (below everyone), child 2 goes second in the stack (above child 3), and lastly child 1 goes last in the stack (above every other item)

Comment: okay sir. names might change. id really doest matter here once he get layout he wanted. thank you for advice.

Comment: I only mentioned it that because of the xml description of how the childs would be placed, which does not match the code (the ids you gave them). Just for better understanding, that's all

Comment: i have udpated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

this is one way to achieve what you want

```
<FrameLayout>

    <ImageView>
    <- Your background image with width and height to match parent ->

    <ImageView>
    <-this is where you put your image->

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This is not right, as the last child is always put on top, however you mentioned "Your background image with width and height to match parent"